# Weird delay when using "tail -f" command

Tags: unix, logging, ssh

To monitor a log file I have to connect to an ssh connection and redirect the output of the log file(let's call it RemoteLog.txt) out to a local machine so it can be read by a java program and put on a GUI.

Right now I have the output redirected out of the ssh connection and onto the local machine with the command:

```
ssh remote@ip.address tail logs/RemoteLog.txt -f > ~/Log/LocalLog.txt
```

and everything works fine technically with one exception: for some reason LocalLog.txt only gets updated with the changes to RemoteLog.txt every 35 seconds to the millisecond.

It doesn't matter the number of changes to RemoteLog, the number of lines specified with the tail command, or using the >> operator vs the > operator; there is always a 35 second delay between updates of LocalLog.txt while RemoteLog is constantly updating.

Does anyone have any clue why this might be?

Comment: Is the date/time of both server identical or do they differ 35 seconds?

Comment: I just tested it and the time is identical on both.

Comment: Did you test `tail -f` on the local machine? `ssh`with other commands like `date`. Remote testprog wruting the date to RemoteLog every 5 seconds?